# Is it possible to create a node.js module which uses c libraries for monetdb connection?

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, monetdb, node-ffi

I am trying to connect `monetdb` with `node.js`. I have a simple (20 line) c program which can query `moentdb` using mapi libraries.

Can I use those libraries to build something(module/addon) for `node.js` which uses these libraries and connect to `monetdb`?

(using odbc is an option but it have its own disadvantages.)

**Update1 :**
node-ffi is pretty awesome. I was able to create a fetch table program pretty easily. (I have added my working code for example.)

So if I have 3 options
1. ODBC
2. node-ffi
3. a c program to fetch database data and listens to connection from node.js through socket

In terms of performance which is better option to implement, if I have little less time to develop a addon for node.js

```
var ffi = require("ffi");
var libmylibrary = ffi.Library('/usr/local/lib/libmapi.so', {
    "mapi_connect":["int",["string",'int',"string","string","string","string"]],
    "mapi_query":['int',["int","string"]],
    "mapi_fetch_row":["int",["int"]],
    "mapi_fetch_field":["string",["int","int"]]
});


var res = libmylibrary.mapi_connect("localhost", 50000,"monetdb", "monetdb", "sql", "demo");
console.log(res);
var ret=libmylibrary.mapi_query(res,"select * from table");
while(libmylibrary.mapi_fetch_row(ret)){
    console.log(libmylibrary.mapi_fetch_field(ret,0));
    console.log(libmylibrary.mapi_fetch_field(ret,1));
}
```

**Update 2:**
Above code is not recommended for production use...it does not use async functionality of node.js so please use it for baby steps

Comment: Try taking a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15393039/why-v8-in-node-js-is-faster-than-in-my-native-c-addon. I came across it one day and found it interesting, and it may be of use to you.

Comment: In c++ addon I have looked at github, full code is written with v8/node headers... I am not sure if a library purely written in c can be added to addon.... I see most of the users criticizing node.js for lack of db libs if it can be done then all dbs can be connected through node.js

Comment: There is a new native Node.js driver module for MonetDB: https://www.npmjs.com/package/monetdb

It is available on npmjs.org, so you can now run ```npm install monetdb``` to install the driver.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While FFI makes it easy to call native code, you really shouldn't use it to for something you have to do often, like calling a database library.  From the docs:

> There is non-trivial overhead associated with FFI calls. Comparing a hard-coded binding version of strtoul() to an FFI version of strtoul() shows that the native hard-coded binding is orders of magnitude faster. So don't just use the C version of a function just because it's faster. There's a significant cost in FFI calls, so make them worth it.

In other words, FFI works, but is *slow*.  This is fine if you just need to make a few calls, but very bad news if you need to make frequent calls.

What you need to do is write an [addon](http://nodejs.org/api/addons.html).  Addons are C++ modules that provide glue to C and C++ libraries.  (Just because you must write the addon in C++ doesn't mean you can't call pure C code from the addon!)

The node [docs](http://nodejs.org/api/addons.html) provide plenty of examples that should get you started.  If you're working with Windows, [here's some tips](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9625030/201952) to get VS set up.

If the calls to the C library are blocking, you'll need to make them async.  [libuv provides a thread pool you can do the work on.](http://nikhilm.github.com/uvbook/threads.html#libuv-work-queue)

Comment: Thanks...people suggested odbc with node-odbc and ffi. But it was advised not to use these methods specially for frequent calls. I saw the docs but coding style was bit different so tried to avoid it. seems I can't avoid writing c++ addon.